# How to initially setup git for personal development on single PC

Tags: windows, git

This is what I do to setup a storage repository that I backup for my personal development.  Is this the best way to do it.

I CD to my designated storage area, in my case d:\sourcecontrol\git

```
git init --bare projectname.git
```

--bare means it is a storage only repository.

I then go to my development folder, eg

D:\development\

and run command:

```
git clone /d/sourcecontrol/git/projectname.git
```

then it creates a new folder projectname here with the .git folder inside.

then create some files to commit

```
git add .
```

that stages the files (adds to list of files to be committed)

```
git commit -m"My first commit"

git push
```

That seems to work fine.  Considering I only need to store on my own PC (I do backups), is this the optimal way to setup for the first time using git?  Any tips?

...

I am thinking I need the backup stage but maybe the push idea is not required.  An alternative could be:

To do the backup:

```
cd /d/development/projectname

git bundle create /d/backups/projectname.bundle master
```

Then if you need to 'restore' on a different computer or your computer fails you can then do this:

```
cd /d/backups/

git clone projectname.bundle -b master /d/development/projectname
```

Comment: Yes, it sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not the optimal way. (It would work, but it's confusing and unnecessarily tedious.) You're thinking git is like SVN with a centralized repository. It's not. Git stores the entire repository in the .git folder with the working copy. So there's no need to make the bare repository at all.

Just do this:

```
cd /d/development
git init 
git add .
git commit -m "My first commit"
```

Instant source control in any folder you want! No need to push anywhere since there's only one copy of the repository.

I'll just add that you can do this wherever you want for as many different projects as you want:

```
cd ~/Some-Random-Project
git init
...
```

Comment: Yes but that doesn't include the "backup" stage.  On a personal project I want a history of my progress which your steps above cover.  but I also want a "copy" of my history - eg if I have to change computers, computer fails, etc.

Comment: @AngusComber Use github, bitbucket or gitorius (to name a few). Or you could set up your own private server.

Comment: Your original question said "I only need to store on my own PC (I do backups)". So you have a backup copy of the repository history (just backup the development folder). Backing up a "bare" repository at /d/sourcecontrol is no safer than backing up the .git folder. There's really no reason to push to /d/sourcecontrol, create a bundle there, or any other such shenanigans. If you want to share code between multiple computers and work on either one, you should get a proper git server set up as Roland suggested.